# Input Validation not set from ngFor generated value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've tried using a blank project and it works. However in my current project that I am working on, I have a bunch of questions that generate dynamic form controls, on the input field. And I have validation set for minlength = 4. The problem is that, when `NgFor` renders the form with the values -- if the value is not meeting the requirement, the inline validation does not fire off until I change something in the input field.

Also, I've noticed when I submit the form, if I do not change the values, they show up as null. but when I make changes, they appear as changed. Been stuck on this component for a few days now... I fix one thing, and another breaks.

```
 <form [formGroup]="pvqForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(pvqForm)" novalidate>
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions | sortBy: 'selected'; let i = index" class="row container-generic">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="container-input-checkbox">
              <label class="container-flex">
              <input formControlName='questionControl{{ question.question_id }}' #checkBox class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" [name]="question.question_id" (change)="checkedState($event, checkBox)" [checked]="isChecked(question)"> 
              <div class="pvq-create-label">
                <div *ngIf="lang == 'en'">
                    <p aria-label="English Question">{{ question.EN }}</p>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="lang == 'fr'">
                    <p aria-label="French Question">{{ question.FR }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </label>
              <label [@hideShow]="checkBox.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'">Answer
              <input minlength=4 formControlName='answerControl{{ question.question_id }}' type="textbox" name="{{ question.question_id }}" [value]="question.answer ? question.answer : ''">
              <div *ngIf="!pvqForm.controls['answerControl' + question.question_id ].valid" style="color: red;">
                {{ "MINLENGTH" | translate }}
              </div>
            </label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    this.pvqForm = new FormGroup({
  answerControl1: this.answer_1,
  answerControl2: this.answer_2,
  answerControl3: this.answer_3,
  answerControl4: this.answer_4,
  answerControl5: this.answer_5,
  answerControl6: this.answer_6,
  answerControl7: this.answer_7,
  answerControl8: this.answer_8,
  answerControl9: this.answer_9,
  answerControl10: this.answer_10,
  answerControl11: this.answer_11,
  answerControl12: this.answer_12,
  answerControl13: this.answer_13,
  answerControl14: this.answer_14,
  answerControl15: this.answer_15,
  answerControl16: this.answer_16,
  answerControl17: this.answer_17,
  answerControl18: this.answer_18,
  answerControl19: this.answer_19,
  answerControl20: this.answer_20,
  questionControl1: this.question_1,
  questionControl2: this.question_2,
  questionControl3: this.question_3,
  questionControl4: this.question_4,
  questionControl5: this.question_5,
  questionControl6: this.question_6,
  questionControl7: this.question_7,
  questionControl8: this.question_8,
  questionControl9: this.question_9,
  questionControl10: this.question_10,
  questionControl11: this.question_11,
  questionControl12: this.question_12,
  questionControl13: this.question_13,
  questionControl14: this.question_14,
  questionControl15: this.question_15,
  questionControl16: this.question_16,
  questionControl17: this.question_17,
  questionControl18: this.question_18,
  questionControl19: this.question_19,
  questionControl20: this.question_20
});

  checkedState(event, checkBox) {
let question_id = checkBox.name;
if (event.target.checked === true) {
  if (this.counter < this.checkedLimit) {
    //Sets validator for newly checked questions
    // this.setValidator(question_id);
    //Add the validator for the checkbox checked
    this.counter++;
  } else {
    event.target.checked = false;
    this.answerControlArr[question_id - 1].setValue(null);
    // this.removeValidator(question_id);
  }
} else if (this.counter > 0) {
  //When clicking off the checkbox, set value to null
  this.answerControlArr[question_id - 1].setValue(null);
  // this.removeValidator(question_id);
  this.counter--;
}
}
```

I tried by also setting validators and removing them dynamically based on the checked state, but no luck. That was causing the form to be invalid.

```
setValidator(questionId) {
//Set Min length Validator
this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setValidators(Validators.minLength(4));
//Set the value
// if(this.questionsArr[questionId - 1][3]){
//   this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setValue(this.questionsArr[questionId - 1][3]);
// }
//Check if Value is "" or does not meet the validator requirement
// if(this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].value == null){
//     this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setErrors({"minLength": true});
// }
if (this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].value == null || this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].value.length < 5) {
  this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setErrors({ "minLength": true });
}
}

  removeValidator(questionId){
this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].clearValidators();
```

}
[image]

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:**
*The same functionality can be achieved with a simpler approach. for example questions can be selected by a button and pushed to the Form, instead of having all of them in our Form from start.*

*But I have chosen this approach to meet question's exact requirements.*

---

When i first started angular, i had similar issues with forms. But the power and simplicity of angular and reactive forms, helped me get through.
Now you are doing your form mainly on template. Instead, you can take full control of it in the model.

### Component

In your component:

```typescript
 export class QuestionsComponent {

      // Our empty Form
      myForm: FormGroup;
      questions = [
         {question: 'Question 1'},
         {question: 'Question 2'},
         {question: 'Question 3'},
         {question: 'Question 4'},
         {question: 'Question 5'},
         {question: 'Question 6'}
      ];

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
          // We inject FormBuilder to our component

          // Now, we instantiate myForm with FormBuilder
          // Notice that myForm is a FormGroup which contains an empty FormArray
           this.myForm = this.fb.group({
                    questions: this.fb.array([])
                }, {validator: this.questionsValidator}
           );

           for (let i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {
               this.addRow(this.questions[i]);
           }
      }
  }
```

Create a new question:

```typescript
initItems(question): FormGroup {
    // Here, we make the form for each question

    return this.fb.group({
        checked: [false],
        question: [question.question],
        answer: [null]
    });
}

 addRow(question) {

    // We get our FormArray
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];

    // instantiate a new question FormGroup;
    let newQuestionGroup = this.initItems(question);

    // Add it to our formArray
    control.push(newQuestionGroup);
}
```

finally we validate our form with a Custom Validator:

```typescript
questionsValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {

        const formData = <FormArray>control.get('questions');
        let answeredCount = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < formData.value.length; i++) {
            let singleQuestion = formData.controls[i];
            if (singleQuestion.value.checked && singleQuestion.value.answer !== null && singleQuestion.value.answer.length > 4) {
                answeredCount += 1;
            }
        }

        return answeredCount >= 5 ? null : {valid: true};
    }
```

### Template

```angular
    <pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>

    <h3>Form is valid: {{myForm.valid}}</h3>

    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <table formArrayName="questions">
            <tr *ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.questions.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" value="bike">
                </td>
                <td>{{myForm.controls.questions.controls[i].value.question}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" min='0' formControlName="answer">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hey, there are 20 questions. I have uploaded a picture to help explain how it looks for further reference.

Comment: I cant see that pic. Can you name question fields?

Comment: I've posted here as well: 
http://tinypic.com/r/tajzhi/9

Each question will be toggled for french and english, thus I have the questions as label for checkbox, and the checkbox as the control.

For simplicity:
Question 1 - EN
Question 1 - FR

as labels

Comment: So checking the Question 5 check box, must make it's answer required. Am i right?

Comment: 5 Questions must be checked and answered out of 20, If 4 are checked and answered you cannot submit. 5 Must be checked and answered, the answers must have a minlength of 4. So yes, answered are required per checked checkbox as well as min length 4.

Comment: This wont work as thr answers are associated with the question and sortef based on selected. Must repopulate the answer fields for each respective qurstion if I was to revisit the page

Comment: Updated to address that.